# Curly braces in a URL

Tags: windows, url, spyware

Often I have came across URLS like the following:

> `http://www.isthisahacker.com/{7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D}.htm`

Do the curly braces in the URL above indicate some kind of attempt to access the registry, or is that a legitimate URL? It looks kind of suspicious to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's just a GUID, a randomly-generated string that's unique to roughly 1 in 4 billion. Could be anything, but a hacker would probably use a less suspicious URL.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be kind of a giveaway, right? Thanks.

Comment: @tslib, I think it's slightly more than 1 in 4 billion - more like 1 in 5,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Answer (score 2):

No, `{ }` are legitimate characters to have an a URL, although it probably should be escaped, so

```
http://www.isthisahacker.com/{7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D}.htm
```

..should technically be:

```
http://www.isthisahacker.com/%7B7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D%7D.htm
```

(where `%7B` and `%7D` are the URL encoded equivalents to `{` and `}`)

There's nothing evil about the symbols, nor the `{7B643FB915-845C-4A76-A071-677D62157FE07D}` string. As tsilb says, it is a [GUID (Globally Unique Identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) - a standardised way of generating random/unique strings.

It's no different to URL like `http://www.isthisahacker.com/4345.htm`